# Avoiding truncation warnings from my C++ compiler when initializing signed values

Tags: c++, initialization, warnings, truncation

I would like to initialize a `short` to a hexadecimal value, but my compiler gives me truncation warnings. Clearly it thinks I am trying to set the `short` to a positive value.

```
short my_value = 0xF00D; // Compiler sees "my_value = 61453"
```

How would you avoid this warning? I could just use a negative value,

```
short my_value = -4083; // In 2's complement this is 0xF00D
```

but in my code it is much more understandable to use hexadecimal.

Comment: If you're trying to assign something with the top bit set, is it really a short? or should you be using an unsigned short?

Answer (score 3):

Cast the constant.

`short my_value = (short)0xF00D;`

EDIT: Initial explanation made sense in my head, but on further reflection was kind of wrong.  Still, this should suppress the warning and give you what you expect.

Comment: I am using C++ so I tried a static_cast, but I still get the warning. Maybe I'm supposed to use reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Using a C-style cast got rid of the warning, thank you. Now I need to read up on why there isn't a C++-style cast to handle this scenario.

Comment: You could `short(0xF00D)`, which is a little more C++-style.  The problem is that there isn't an integer literal to specify a `short int` like there is for a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an int value that can not fit short, hence the warning. You could silent the compiler by using a c-type cast, but it is usually a bad practice.

A better way is not to do that, and to assign a negative value. Or, if the hexadecimal value makes more sense, to switch to unsigned short.