# Is it possible to completely avoid C-style casts in C++?

Tags: c++, c, casting

I do not believe that it is possible to completely avoid C-style casts when writing C++. I was surprised to [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219160/avoiding-truncation-warnings-from-my-c-compiler-when-initializing-signed-values) that I needed to use a C-style cast to avoid a compiler truncation warning:

```
short value_a = 0xF00D;                     // Truncation warning in VS2008
short value_b = static_cast<short>(0xF00D); // Truncation warning in VS2008
short value_c = (short)0xF00D;              // No warning!
```

Are there other scenarios where there is no C++-style substitute for a C-style cast?

Comment: `short value_c(0xF00D)` -- also: which compiler is giving you truncation warnings? My GCC is smart enough not to in all three situations.

Comment: C++ casts cover for all the C cast operator uses.

Comment: As far as the language cares, there's no difference between `static_cast` and a C-style cast in this case. If the compiler decided to give a warning that "it's 3AM local time -- you should really go to bed", it's free to do that though...

Comment: @TravisGockel that may or may not issue a warning about truncation. If `sizeof(short)` is 1 then this will truncate.

Comment: @wilhemltell: not so. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346616/need-clarifications-in-c-style-reinterpret-and-const-casts/2346658#2346658

Comment: What compiler are you using? **I don’t get any warning** even with `g++ -Wall -Wextra` (where `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(short) == 2`. Of course if that’s not the case the compiler is warning for a good reason, and you should *not* try to shut it up!)

Comment: @wilhelmtell: In those cases, you wouldn't *want* the warning to go away.  If implicit constant conversion is going to screw up, that is a great warning to have.

Comment: Which compiler produces this error? IMO, `static_cast` is meant for such cases...

Comment: @TravisGockel maybe yes, maybe not. What if the value is guaranteed to be low enough? Then you **don't** want to see the warning. Dummy warnings hide **real, important, relevant** warnings.

Comment: @UncleBens: While errors and warning are both _diagnostics_, they aren't the same. The OP got a _warning_, not an _error_. The standard doesn't care, but in practice this is quite a difference.

Comment: Just throwing this out there: **the result of `reinterpret_cast` is implementation-defined**. To say "A C-style cast can be replaced with a `reinterpret_cast`" is just bogus; C-style casts aren't necessarily implementation-defined. (Unless you're `reinterpret_cast`'ing a POd to `char&`, etc, yadda-yadda.)

Comment: @wilhelmtell: That means we agree on my original point -- the compiler should be smart enough to figure this out and not issue a warning here.  OP is not using GCC or LLVM, since neither of them issue a warning here.

Comment: @sbi: Sorry, I meant *warning*. It doesn't seem to be the case with VC++ either.

Comment: 0xF00d can not fit in short because it is larger than max_short (0x7FFF). Use unsigned short instead.

Comment: @Dialecticus: According to the standard, there can be platforms out there where a `short` is 47 bits wide.

Comment: @sbi: Of course, but in this particular case maximum short is 0x7FFF, hence the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just trying to obfuscate your code, it is as simple as that. And the compiler is completely correct in telling you so.

If you have a precise idea what the assigned value should be, use that. My guess is that you have some unfounded presumption of `short` being 16 bit wide and that the sign representation of the target machine is two's complement. If that is so, assign -4083 to your variable. If you just need your variable as a bit vector, use an unsigned type.

As far as C is concerned the standard simply says about conversion from one integer type to another:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and
>   the value cannot be represented in it;
>   either the result is
>   implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is
>   raised.

I imagine the the point of view of C++ with this respect is not much different. Other answers mention border cases where in C++ you would need a `C'-style cast to overrule all typechecks that C++ gives you. Feeling the need for them is an indication of bad design.

The case that you give as an example is certainly not one for which I would find any valid circumstances.

Answer (score 13):

In C++, the C-style cast is defined (§5.4) in terms of C++-style casts. So for every cast you can do C-style, there's a matching C++-style cast (almost).

The "almost" is that C-style casts ignore base class accessibility. That is, there is no equivalent C++-style cast for the following:

```
struct foo {};
struct bar : private foo {};

bar b;
foo* f = (foo*)&b; // only way this can be done in a well-defined manner
```

So, no it's not strictly-speaking possible to completely ditch C-style casts. But the number of areas where a (combination  of) C++-style casts doesn't suffice is few in count.

---

The above is the "language answer". What you're experiencing has nothing to do with C-style casts versus C++ casts, but just compiler implementation. Warnings are absolutely implementation-specific, and have nothing to do with C++.

So don't make the mistake of using your findings *on this particular compiler in this particular situation* for concluding things *about C++ in general*.

Comment: `foo* f = reinterpret_cast<foo*>(&b)` ?  Although I'm assuming you forgot the `&` from `foo* f = (foo*)b`.

Comment: @Travis: Nope. The result of `reinterpret_cast` is **implementation-defined**. With the C-style cast, it acts like a `static_cast` which is not implementation-defined.

Comment: @GMan: clearly, it does *not* act like a `static_cast` in the OP’s case. Otherwise it would give a warning. Since there is none, I conclude that it acts like the `reinterpret_cast` here. Or the compiler has a bug. Take your pick.

Comment: +1 for not using the compiler to tell you what is truth according to the standard.

Comment: "but you'd be hard-pressed to find a good situation where it's needed.". CRTP with a private or protected base class is definitely a good use-case of it. I've used it for that, together with `boost::is_base_of` (which can detect private inheritance) for ensuring inheritance.

Comment: @Konrad: Huh? Where did I say anything about it acting like `static_cast` for OP? Warnings and compliance have nothing to do with each other, so you should rethink your argument. I could have a fully compliant compiler that emits a warning every other line because I felt like it. @sbi: Urg, typo. @Johannes: Fair, I've weakend the statement a bit.

Comment: @GMan: What else did you refer to, if not OP’s code? Your example (private inheritance) doesn’t even compile when using `static_cast` so I assumed you weren’t referring to that. – Fair comment about the warning (although I would *still* think that warning about a well-defined operation is borderline to a bug).

Comment: @Konrad: Can you clarify what you mean by "refer to"? What text are you seeing? The one to Travis? We were talking about my snippet, which cannot be replaced with `static_cast` but acts like one. In other words, using the C-style cast there is like making the base public instead of private, then using `static_cast`.

Comment: @GMan: that clears it up (“cannot be replaced with … but acts like one“). I misconstrued what you meant by “acts like” above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is completely possible.

I never use C-style casts.  I can write hundreds of thousands of lines of code without having to revert to using `reinterpret_cast`, C++'s closest cousin to the C-style cast.  The only times I have to use `reinterpret_cast` is when doing socket programming -- a fairly narrow domain, in the big picture.

*You* don't *need* to use C-style casts, either.  In your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219160/avoiding-truncation-warnings-from-my-c-compiler-when-initializing-signed-values), you said

> I could just use a negative value,

```
short my_value = -4083;
```

> but in my code it is much more understandable to use hexadecimal.

So in this case you didn't have to use the cast.  You chose to.

Comment: Recently, I had to use a reinterpret_cast to convert from a raw unsigned char array to an instance of a struct. Is this something like what you were saying, about the sockets?

Comment: @San.  Maybe. :)  I'd have to see it.

Comment: I'd up-vote to counter the inexplicable down-vote, but I ran out of votes for today. `:(` But, yeah, for me, too, the LoC/`reinterpret_cast` ration is somewhere in the six-digit numbers, and I don't think I've used a c-style cast in C++ code in the last decade.

Comment: @sbi:  I must have a random hater.

Comment: Might be better than a random lover. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 c++ style casts, const_cast, reinterpret_cast, static_cast and dynamic_cast. They work as follows:

```
// const_cast casts away constness or adds it
const int const_integer = 5;
const_cast<int>(const_integer) = 3;

// static_cast will perform standards defined casts and will 
// cast up or down a c++ inheritance hierarchy without checking the result of the cast
struct b {};
struct a : public b {};
struct c {};
double value = static_cast<double>(0.0f);
b* b_value = new b;
a* a_value = static_cast<a*>(b_value);

// dynamic_cast will perform any cast that static_cast will, but will check to see
// if the cast makes sense. If the values are not pointers, this cast can throw
b* value_b = new b;
a* value_a = new a;
b* new_b = dynamic_cast<b*>(value_a); // will return NULL
a* new_a = dynamic_cast<a*>(value_b); // will not return NULL    

// reinterpret_cast will change any type to any other type, as long as the constness of the types is the same.
// the behavior of this cast is implementation specific.
double* a = new double;
*a = 0.0f;
int *b = reinterpret_cast<int*>(a);
```

A c-style cast in c++ simply tries to perform those casts in a specific order until one of them works. That order is as follows:

- a const_cast
- a static_cast
- a static_cast followed by a const_cast
- a reinterpret_cast, or
- a reinterpret_cast followed by a const_cast.

So, in short, you can do any c-style cast in c++, because a c-style cast in c++ is just some arrangement of c++ style casts. Get it?

Comment: See my answer, then. Not every case can be replaced with C++-style casts.

Comment: Your first `const_cast` example results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: How does it result in undefined behavior?

Comment: the `const_cast` itself doesn't cause undefined behavior, but modifying the object that actually is `const` does.  Just because you can cast away the `const` qualifier doesn't mean you're allowed to actually modify a const object.

Answer (score 0):

> I was surprised to find out that I needed to use a C-style cast to avoid a compiler truncation warning

I see it the other way around: You use a C-style cast to ***prevent the compiler from warning you***,  and I see this as a severe disadvantage of the C-style cast.

if you feel you know what you're doing, then shut up the compiler for this one case by using a compiler-specific way. For example, for VC use something like

```
#pragma warning(push, disable: XXXX)
// code goes here
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Comment: I would never have thought to do this, probably because we use at least 3 different compilers/compiler families to compile the same code for different targets, and a cast seems cleaner to me than doing all of the preprocessor checking to determine the compiler each time I could have just used a cast. What is your thought?

Comment: @San: I have been part of a project were most of the code was compiled by half a dozen different compilers and versions thereof, times several different std lib implementations. Still, most of us tried to avoid using C-style casts, because they shut up the compiler completely, preventing it from pointing out errors. (And every error found through compiling is worth 1000 found at run-time, usually by a customer.) IME experience __different compilers will vary wildly in what they warn about__ anyway, so usually you need to shut them up (selectively) at different places.

Comment: Make that `#pragma warning(suppress: XXXX)` perhaps?

Comment: @Matt: That `suppress` is something I hadn't heard about yet.

Answer (score -3):

In these cases, you can use `reinterpret_cast`. It was meant for a replacement of a unchecked C-style cast. The typical note here: this is unchecked cast, and should be avoided when possible by using the other available: `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, etc.

Comment: Actually, C-style cast can be one of 5 combinations of `static_cast`, `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Good answer..blah, blah, blah... yadda, yadda... don't use this mehod unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: I don't think a `reinterpret_cast` should be use to truncate an `int` to a `short`. Ever.